# Boot Problems & Partitioning Questions - Running Ubuntu 16.04 (Legacy Mode) on UEFI HP Pavilion g6 Laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

Here's a bit of a history that might (or might not!) shed some light on my current problems.

I have an HP Pavilion g6 laptop that came with Windows 7 pre-installed, it worked like a charm. A year ago, Windows 10 was forced down my throat and started wreaking havoc on my machine. I installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 on dual boot and everything worked fine. I stopped using windows completely so I opted to uninstall it and stick with Ubuntu full time.

OS-Uninstaller could not (for some mysterious reason) get rid of Windows 10, so I manually formatted the partition which housed it. I updated grub to point directly to ubuntu and it worked just fine.

18.04 rolled out and I started to upgrade. This is where the fun began!

During the upgrade process, something went haywire and my upgrade crashed. I rebooted and tried to salvage the process using dpkg. The upgrade went on and after another reboot, my desktop environment was gone, I could only log in using tty3. I tried to reinstall my missing packages and the desktop environment, but I was confronted continuously with "unmet dependencies" errors during the update/upgrade process.

I ran my Ubuntu live USB, erase my previous install and reinstalled 16.04. I think this corrupted my bootloader or something! Now, my laptop boots to grub command line and I have to manually go to BIOS boot options and point to the Ubuntu HDD boot (which got installed in legacy mode not EFI!) every time I boot up.

Due to having formatted my Windows partition my HDD map looks cluttered and not ideal (screen shot link). 
[HDD Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKNsv.png)

So now I don't know what to do. I am thinking of erasing my entire HDD, reinstall Ubuntu and repartition. But I am worried about a couple of things:

1. The Bios-flagged partition in the center of my partition table. Will it cause more boot issues?
2. If I wipe the entire hard drive during the reinstall, what happens to my EFI partition? Will it get wiped as well? Will a new one be created?
3. How can I reinstall Ubuntu in EFI not Legacy Mode?

P.S: If I go ahead with a fresh install on a wiped HDD, I will be installing Ubuntu Mate' 18.04 LTS. (Currently downloading)

Let me know if i need to provide any more information. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to install a fresh by erasing HDD..boot in UEFI mode.. go to something else and first create EFI partition of 100mb then for ext4 mounted to / as per your choice.. Leave the remaining place unallocated and install Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks @PRATAP!   -  Your advice worked wonderfully. Cheers!